# Python 3 Airflow scheduled job does not run

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I set up my job to run everyday at 9:00 UTC.

I have the following arguments for my DAG:

```
start_date= datetime(2018, 8, 15)
schedule_interval='0 9 * * *'
```

I deployed the job on 2018-08-16 around 17:00 UTC. I was expecting it to run on 2018-08-17 9:00 UTC but it did not. Any reason why?

Comment: @tobi6 yea, there are no task instances for 2018-08-17.

Comment: What does the log say (found in AIRFLOW_HOME)? Perhaps a job is stuck and needs to cleared--what's the 'depends_on_past' set to?  Or missing an import?

Comment: What about other instances? Is nothing shown at all?

Comment: The ones I forced show up as successful

Answer (score 2):

There's a conflict between your start time and the scheduler interval. The start date says run starting at midnight (since there's no hour), while the cron job says run at 9am.  Since you want this to run daily anyway - set scheduler_interval to '@daily' and put the 9 in your start_date.

For example:

```
start_date= datetime(2018, 8, 15, 9)
schedule_interval='@daily'
```

If you already have history for this I'd suggest clearing the history so that doesn't override your start date.